# How to flatten a GroupBy and select in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that's returning some grouped data, and I'm drawing a blank on how to "flatten" it so that top level information is available at each group.

```
Account A
    - Group A
    - Group B
    - Group C
    - etc

Account B
    - Group B
    - Group C
```

What I want to do is "flatten" this to:

```
Account A | Group A | Sum(Group)
Account A | Group B | Sum(Group)
Account A | Group C | Sum(Group)
Account B | Group B | Sum(Group)
Account B | Group C | Sum(Group)
```

Here's what I have so far, but I'm not totally sure where to go

```
var transactions = Accounts.Where(clause)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Account = x,
        TransGroupedByBucket = x.TransactionLogs.GroupBy(tl => tl.TransactionType.BucketTypeID)
    })

    //pseudocode
    //Select  new {
    //   Account,
    //   One_TransactionLog_Group
    //}

    //will run for each group:
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AccountInfo = x.Account.ID
        Sum = One_TransactionLog_Group.Sum(tl => tl.Amount)
    })
    ;
```

I think I'm just having a brain fart, can someone point me in the right direction? One idea I had was to flip it to start at the `TransactionLog` level and traverse to the `Account`, but there might be 0 `TransactionLog`s for an `Account`, so that might not work properly.

Comment: `Accounts.SelectMany(x => return x.TransactionLogs.Select(y => new { Account = x.ID, TransactionLog = y, Sum = ... }))`

Comment: i think that's what i'm looking for. I guess i was thinking there was a way i could do the final selects at the "top level", but i guess they'll have to be *inside* the `SelectMany`

Comment: yes, that did it for me, if you'd like to put an answer down. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SelectMany`:

```
Accounts.SelectMany(x => x.TransactionLogs.
                           Select(y => new { Account = x.ID,
                                             TransactionLog = y,
                                             Sum = ... });
```

Comment: Thanks again. I knew it was something with a `SelectMany`, but I wasn't thinking of doing the final select as a "subquery" of the `SelectMany`, that was the piece i was missing.